# How do I send video to a separate monitor in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: video, monitor

How do I send video to a monitor through a video cable from my laptop?
I am using Ubuntu 14.04. In windows 7 I hit <kbd>F8</kbd>. Is it that easy?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to accomplish this task, my preferred one is:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1366x768 --right-of eDP1
```

- **VGA1**: is my output connected to the other monitor, it can be HDMI1, or whatever.
- **--mode**: defines the resolution of the monitor.
- **--right-of**: says put the new monitor at right side of the active one, it can be --same-as (which mirrors the display) or --left-of too.
- **eDP1**: is my laptop display.

Another way is:
Search for display in dash and use it to setup your preferred configs.
[more information.](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-dual-monitors.html)

[image]